# Does an AudioWorkletNode need to be connected to BaseAudioContext.destination?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have an AudioWorkletNode that only takes an input to perform visualization of audio. It outputs nothing, and yet, nothing is happening unless I connect it to BaseAudioContext.destination. This seems silly if it's intentionally designed this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Chrome since this is the only browser which supports the `AudioWorkletNode` so far. In that case it is a known issue. Unless something is connected to the `destination` Chrome will not process it. The `ScriptProcessorNode` does for example suffer from the same problem.

I tried to find a tracking bug on [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org) but couldn't find one. Therefore I created one: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1045926

A library that I maintain called [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context) has a fix for that, although it might be overkill if this is the only workaround you need.

Comment: Hmm, I thought this was fixed so that AudioWorklets don't need to be connected, just like AnalyserNodes don't need to be connected.

Comment: I have a test that I run in every version of Chrome which still keeps failing. https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context/blob/master/test/expectation/chrome/any/audio-worklet-node.js#L47 It looks like the problem still persists.

Comment: Hey +chrisguttandin, can you file an issue about this? It's generally supposed to work.

Comment: I created a bug (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1045926) and also updated the answer.